# Share user object between several react_components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, react-rails

What is the best way to share a user object between multiple `react_component` other than hanging it off of window?

For example -

```rb
<%= react_component("HelloWorld1", { user: @user }) %>
<%= react_component("HelloWorld2", { user: @user }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

##### If you're using React and HTML.ERB for the frontend

I think the way you currently have it is the best way to do it if you want to combine HTML.ERB and React.

*Just as you can't pass down a prop to two components at once when dealing with pure React, I don't think you can do it in this case too*.

##### If you're only using React for the frontend

*Note: I'm not sure how the following would affect SEO.*

You could use the Rails app as an API, and display your React app using a single HTML tag in `static_pages#root` (or similar). And then use [`react-router-dom`](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for routing and changing pages on the frontend.

That way you don't have to keep rendering `html.erb` templates that you may pass instance variables to. You'd be fetching data and modifying it using API requests.

---

#### Extra details

If you choose to do the second method (using [`react-router-dom`](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)), then the files might look something similar to the following:

`routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, default: { format: :json } do
    resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
    # ...
  end
  root to: 'static_pages#root'
end
```

`app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb`

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def root
  end
end
```

`app/views/static_pages/root.html.erb`

```
<main>
  <%= react_component("App") %>
</main>
```

`app/javascript/components/App.jsx`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Auth } from './auth/Auth.jsx';
import { HelloWorld1 } from './hello/world1/HelloWorld1.jsx';
import { HelloWorld2 } from './hello/world1/HelloWorld2.jsx';

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  if (!user) {
   return (
     <Auth setUser={setUser} />
   );
  }

  return (
     <Switch>
      <Route 
       exact
       path="/hello/world1" 
       render={(props) => <HelloWorld1 user={user} {...props} />}
      />

      <Route 
       exact
       path="/hello/world2" 
       render={(props) => <HelloWorld2 user={user} {...props} />}
      />

      {/* ... */}
    </Switch>
};

export default App;
```